# How to create a Model for dynamic keys , json parsing ,swift5

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, codable

I am parsing a json data and trying to create a Model but can't figure out how to achieve the title and extract properties from the json data (which I have provided), as `pageids` property is dynamic. Please tell me how can I create Model to extract the `title` property from the page using id (stored in `pageids` property)

link for jsonData https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?exintro=&titles=canterbury%20bells&indexpageids=&format=json&pithumbsize=500&explaintext=&redirects=1&action=query&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages

I tried little a bit, below is my code but I don't think that's correct

```
var ID = ""
struct Document:Codable {
    
    let batchcomplete:String
    let query:Query
}
struct Query:Codable {
    let normalized:[Normalized]
    
    let pages:Pages
    
    var pageids:[String]{
        didSet{
            ID = oldValue[0]
        }
    }
    
}

struct Normalized:Codable {
    let from:String
    let to:String // it is a name of an flower
}
struct Pages:Codable {
    let id:[Pages2]
    enum CodingKeys:CodingKey {
        case id = "\(ID)"
    }
}
struct Pages2:Codable {
    let title:String // this is an official name of flower
    let extract:String // this is a body
    let thumbnail:Thumbnail
}
struct Thumbnail:Codable {
    let source:String //this is an url for photo
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model to map your JSON will be something like this:

```
struct Document: Codable {
    let batchcomplete: String
    let query: Query
}

struct Query: Codable {
    let normalized: [Normalized]
    var pageids: [String]
    let pages: [String: Page]
}

struct Normalized: Codable {
    let from: String
    let to: String
}

struct Page: Codable {
    let title: String
    let extract: String
    let thumbnail: Thumbnail
}
struct Thumbnail: Codable {
    let source: String
}
```

and you have access to each page using `pageids` array and `pages` dictionary:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(Document.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    decoded.query.pageids.forEach { id in
        guard let page = decoded.query.pages[id] else { return }
        print(page.title)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

However I would prefer to make a small change to the model in order to make access to pages easier. That will require to customly implement the decoding of `Query` struct:

```
struct Query: Decodable {
    let normalized: [Normalized]
    let pages: [Page]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case normalized
        case pageids
        case pages
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        normalized = try container.decode([Normalized].self, forKey: .normalized)
        
        let pageids = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .pageids)
        let pagesDict = try container.decode([String: Page].self, forKey: .pages)
        pages = pageids.compactMap { pagesDict[$0] }
    }
}
```

Then, access to each page would be as simple as a loop:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(Document.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    decoded.query.pages.forEach { page in
        print(page.title)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```