# Creating Decode Path from JSON Data in Swift that Includes Numbers and Hyphens?

Tags: json, swift, struct, decode, let

this is relatively new to me and I've searched high and low but have been unsuccessful in finding a similar scenario.

I have retrieved some JSON Data from an API URL and have successfully decoded and output various values from this data as strings by parsing the data to a  separate sheet and using structs and constants with the 'Decodable' value set. The problem I have is that one of the containers in the Json data is a hyphenated date in this format dates['2020-11-04'] so swift will not let me create a struct with this name (also this looks like an array but there are no square brackets when viewing the unformatted JSON data in a web browser).

Here is the full path to the date I want to output as a string and the URL being used (copied from a web browser using JSON Viewer Pro):

dates['2020-11-04'].countries.Afghanistan.date

https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2020-11-04

Here is the sheet containing my Structs and constants to decode the data:

```
import Foundation

//I understand the below name will not work but i've included it to show my presumed process
struct CovidData: Decodable {
    let dates: dates[2020-11-04]
}

//Once again the below struct name does not work but i've included it as an example of my presumed process.
struct dates[2020-11-04]: Decodable {
    let countries: countries
}

struct countries: Decodable {
    let Afghanistan: Afghanistan
}
struct Afghanistan: Decodable {
    let date: String
}
```

Here is my management sheet with my API call and JSON Parse:

```
import Foundation

protocol CovidDataManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateCovidData(_ covidDataManager: CovidDataManager, covid: CovidModel)
}

struct CovidDataManager {
    
    var delegate: CovidDataManagerDelegate?
    
    let covidURL = "https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2020-11-04"
    
    func getData() {
        let urlString  = covidURL
        performRequest(with:urlString)
        
    }
    
    func performRequest(with urlString: String){
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error")
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let covid = parseJSON(safeData){
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateCovidData(self, covid: covid)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        
        func parseJSON(_ covidData: Data) -> CovidModel?  {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CovidData.self, from: covidData)
                let date = decodedData.dates['2020-11-04'].countries.Afghanistan.date
                let covid = CovidModel(date: date)
                print(date)
                return covid
            } catch {
                print("Error with JSON Parse")
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have not included my UI update sheet as mentioned before the call and decode is working perfectly fine when decoding data with a JSON path made up entirely of strings it is only this container with additional symbols and numbers I am stumped with.

Hopefully I've supplied enough information and apologies if some of the terminology isn't accurate, this is still quite new to me.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know your "JSON Viewer Pro", but clearly, there is nowhere in the JSON `'2020-11-04'`. It's unclear why you really want that `'`character. You shouldn't need to. Also, you might want to skip it. Same as the solution there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678573/how-to-create-a-model-for-dynamic-keys-json-parsing-swift5/64713884#64713884 (user proposal).

Comment: Unfortunately the structure in a web browser goes 'Dates > 2020-11-04 > countries > Afghanistan' all of the solutions I am finding have sample code where the names of the structure (or constants) are strings of text whereas the route to the data I need to get to has numbers and hyphens. If I could skip this container then that would be helpful but I don't see how to do that from the link.

Comment: No, there is no "hyphened dates", that's only maybe in JSON View Pro, but not in reality.

Comment: So my structure to decode should follow this path....

struct CovidData: Decodable {
    let dates: dates

}

struct dates: Decodable {
    let countries: countries
}

struct countries: Decodable {
    let Afghanistan: Afghanistan
}
struct Afghanistan: Decodable {
    let date: String
}

Comment: This is the data without using a JSON viewer in a web browser, it does seem to have the date in the path, ignoring this still doesn't seem to work for me in swift.

{"dates":{"2020-11-04":{"countries":{"Afghanistan":{"date":"2020-11-04","id":"afghanistan","links":[{"href":"/api/2020-11-

Comment: Quickly done: https://pastebin.com/RRp07FWr There is still works to do, but that could be a base.

Comment: Great, Thank you! That worked perfectly with a bit of tinkering.